# using same Java SAXParser in a row

Tags: java, saxparser

I am having the following scenario using `Java SAXParser`:

```
InputStream is1 =... //some initialization of input stream
parser.parse(is1,this);
Closeables.closeQuietly(is1);
InputStream is2=...// intialization of another input stream  
parser.parse(is2,this);  
Closeables.closeQuietly(is2);
```

The question is whether do i have to take any actions between parsing of `is1` and `is2` to make it work properly, i.e. some kind of *parser re-initalization*?

Thanks.

Comment: you want parse xml using SAX...?

Comment: it seems that SAXParser that i have implements "parse" using XMLReader, so it makes sense to parse xml using this SAXParser.